# setup skaffold to deploy changes to google cloud build

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-build, skaffold

i'm new to skaffold and have setup the yaml file as below which should sync any changes in the src folder in my project to goolge cloud build. Please note Im not using git.

When I run skaffold dev any changes in the src folder on the local machine (macos) are synced to google cloud build i.e the image is updated and deployed.

If I make any changes within src folder while skaffold dev is running, I notice skaffold identifies the changes but are not deployed to google cloud build.

How can i update the below yaml file which will also deploy the changes to google cloud build everytime i make a change any file within src folder. Currently I have to stop skaffold and rerun it for the changes to be deployed in google cloud build.

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "auth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node-dev src/index.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.12",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.12.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.6",
    "typescript": "^4.3.4"
  }
}
```

### skaffold.yaml

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  # local:
  #   push: false
  googleCloudBuild:
    projectId:  ticketing-dev
  artifacts:
    - image: gcr.io/ticketing-dev/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
```

### Docker File

```
FROM node:alpine

#create working dir within image called app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

### Below is auth-depl.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec: 
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: gcr.io/ticketing-dev/auth
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

Comment: That's interesting since `skaffold dev` should be able to deploy those changes, could you provide any logs for this process?

Comment: below is the skaffold log when i make change and save the file:
Syncing 1 files for gcr.io/ticketing-dev/auth:latest@sha256:1db861d64340e900e5b1721086c69613f1025261f4119f28b1539094068701a0

Answer (score 0):

Skaffold syncs changes to the running containers, not GCB.  One of the requirements is that the container must contain `tar`.

You haven't included your `Dockerfile`, but one key point is that syncing files may not be sufficient: your app needs to detect and reload the changes.  Most typescript apps use `tsc-watch` to recompile and relaunch.

For example, I see something like the following using the Skaffold [TypeScript example](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/blob/master/examples/typescript/README.md):

```
[node] 2:22:47 PM - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
[node] Example app listening on port 3000.
Syncing 1 files for node-typescript-example:21b757dbdb147a87b0ce4b1e538ab93cdbc114e99515fdf4e398ed62a2b3809d
Watching for changes...
[node] 2:22:52 PM - File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...
[node] 
[node] 
[node] 2:22:52 PM - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
[node] Example app listening on port 3000!
```

The `[node]` lines are from within the container.

Comment: i have included the dockerfile and yaml files in the original post